# Understanding function to find mode

Tags: javascript, mode, find-occurrences

Hope this is an ok question to ask here...
So I got a little help creating a function to find mode (the number which appears the most time in an array). But now I need a little help understanding it...
(I'm totally new in programming)
    Data is holding the "information", contains multiple arrays in another file.

```
let mode = function(data) {
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;    
  });
  let mode = {},
  highestOccurrence = 0,
  modes = [];
  data.forEach(function(element) {
    if (mode[element] === undefined) {
      mode[element] = 1;
    } else {
      mode[element]++;
    }
    if (mode[element] > highestOccurrence) {
      modes = [element];
      highestOccurrence = mode[element];
    } else if (mode[element] === highestOccurrence) {
      modes.push(element);
      highestOccurrence = mode[element];
    }
  });
  return modes;
};
```

So at first I'm just sorting the function so the numbers will appear in corret order. But could someone be so kind to help me understand the rest of the function?

Comment: please fix `data1.forEach` to `data.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

I've added some comments that I could infer only be the code you provided. You could provide some more context to your question like what is the kind of data you have and what are you trying to achieve and maybe provide examples that could be useful.

```
let mode = function(data) {
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;    
  });
  let mode = {},
  highestOccurrence = 0,
  modes = [];

  // This loops through data array (It should be data here and not data1)
  data.forEach(function(element) {

    // Here you check if the mode object already have that element key,  
    // setting the first occurence or incrementing it

    if (mode[element] === undefined) {
      mode[element] = 1;
    } else {
      mode[element]++;
    }

    // After that it checks if that mode has the higher occurence

    if (mode[element] > highestOccurrence) {

      // If it has the higher occurence it sets the modes to an array with
      // that element and the highestOccurrence value to that value
      modes = [element];
      highestOccurrence = mode[element];

    } else if (mode[element] === highestOccurrence) {
      // If it has the same number of occurences it just adds that mode to
      // the modes to be returned
      modes.push(element);
      highestOccurrence = mode[element];
    }
  });
  return modes;
};
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: For example I have this array: ([20, 4, 1, 2, -1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 20, 20])
And I'm supposed to make functions to find max, min, mean, median, mode and range.
But the comments you added really helped me understand a lot, thanks!

Comment: @taguenizy ... you never gave it a try - the code should throw an error as much as the OP's example will do since there is an indifference with operating `data1` vs the passed `data`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I assumed it was a typo. He wanted to understand what it was doing, not why it wasn't working. But I'll correct it in my response

Comment: it should say data in both, it was a typo that I now have corrected.

Comment: Thanks for both edits - now the answer can be upvoted.